# How can I add a search button to this HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I add a button next to the search field?

This is a list jQuery filter. I have copied this from w3school.  The Search is working automatically in this code but I want the search to be done by a button.

It will be very helpful for me if anyone can help me with this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Filterable Table</h2>
<p>Type something in the input field to search the table for first names, last names or emails:</p>  
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<br><br>

<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@mail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>Dooley</td>
    <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anja</td>
    <td>Ravendale</td>
    <td>a_r@test.com</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  
<p>Note that we start the search in tbody, to prevent filtering the table headers.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *copied this from w3school* - that was your first mistake... (it's *not* held in very high regard due to numerous errors, but it's ok as a beginning/learning resource)

Comment: 1) add a button.  2) give it an id  3) change `$("#myInput").on("keyup"` to `$("#myButton").on("click"`

Comment: SO community is a bit touchy about "do this for me", so assuming you want help rather than just someone do it for you (after all you are looking in w3schools, presumably to learn), I've reworded to *if anyone can help me with this*

Comment: @freedomn-m, I don’t think that would work because later it uses `$(this)`, which if you changed that, would refer to the button, not the input.

Comment: step 4) change `var value = $(this).val()` to `var value = $("#myInput").val()` (but make sure you know why the 2nd/3rd `this` isn't also changed and what they refer to)

Comment: Add this button `<button id="searchBtn">Search</button>` to html and use this jquery code `$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchBtn").on("click", function() {
    var value = $("#myInput").val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});`

Comment: @Davedude good call, I was trying to not to just provide a complete solution / all the code needed.  eg "add a button" **rather than spoon-feed the button code**.  But that was a worthy addition.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Thank you. It's working.

Comment: @HazratAli, no problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use event click with button:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").on("click", function() {
    var value = $('#myInput').val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Filterable Table</h2>
<p>Type something in the input field to search the table for first names, last names or emails:</p>  
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<button id="button">Search</button>
<br><br>

<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@mail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>Dooley</td>
    <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anja</td>
    <td>Ravendale</td>
    <td>a_r@test.com</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  
<p>Note that we start the search in tbody, to prevent filtering the table headers.</p>

</body>
</html>
```